# Check if category is child of another

Tags: category-tree, list-view

I know how to check what the parent category id is, but what I am trying to do is find out if the current category is a child of a specific category, up to 2 levels deep.

For example: if user is browsing child2 in category1/child1/child2, detecting if child2 is a child of category1

Is there a function that handles this?

Or

should I create a helper with an iterator that climbs up the tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pull the path of the current category:

```
$path = $category->getPath();
```

The path contains the location in the category tree of the current category separated by a `/`.  You can do the following to iterate through each category in the path to search for the one you are interested in as being a parent:

```
$path = explode('/', $path);
array_pop($path); // throw away the current category
array_pop($path); // throw away the parent category
$gparent = array_pop($path); // this is the category you are interested in
```

If you want to search any category in the tree for the particular parent you could just use a foreach loop:

```
$path = explode('/', $path);
array_pop($path); // throw away the current category
array_shift($path); // throw away the highest level category which is always 1 (and you don't even see in the tree)
foreach ($path as $p):
    if ($p == $gparent):
        // do something here
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: worked great, although for some reason I had to pull it from the registry, as `$this->getcurrentCategory()` didn't return an object. Not sure why, it was being called from the list view.